# CSV file in amazon s3 to amazon SQL Server rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

Is there any sample where I can find how to copy data from a CSV file inside Amazon S3 into a Microsoft SQL Server Amazon RDS ?

In the documentation its only mentioned about importing data from a local db into RDS.

Answer (score 0):

Approach would be like - You have to spin up an EC2 instance and copy S3 CSV files into it and then from there you have to use Bulk insert command. Example:

```
BULK INSERT SchoolsTemp
FROM 'Schools.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
```

All this can be stitched together in AWS Data Pipeline.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  The AWS / RDS docs say BULK INSERT is not supported:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they setup Sql Server RDS integration with S3.  I found [this aws docs article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/User.SQLServer.Options.S3-integration.html) which explains it in good detail.

After you've setup the proper credentials, it appears they added specific stored procedures to download (and upload/delete) to a `D:\S3` directory.  I haven't personally done this, but I thought I would share since the comment on the other post mentions that `BULK INSERT` isn't supported.  But this would provide a way for `BULK INSERT` to work using a file from s3.

Copy the file to the RDS instance:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_download_from_s3
        @s3_arn_of_file='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/bulk_data.csv',
        @rds_file_path='D:\S3\seed_data\data.csv',
        @overwrite_file=1;
```

Then run the `BULK INSERT`:

```
BULK INSERT MyData
FROM 'D:\S3\seed_data\data.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```